# trace oracle statements

Tags: sql, oracle, trace, toad

I'm developing an app using Oracle database and I would surely like to have an SQL statements tracer that could trace sessions and processes statements - like Toad's SQL Tracker/Monitor. But since the good one cost alot of money I'm thinking about building a small one myself.
Any ideeas about wich would be the best solution for tracing oracle sql statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sql Plus + tkprof.

```
alter session set timed_statistics = true; 
alter session set sql_trace = true; 
show parameter user_dump_dest



tkprof <trc-файл> <txt-файл>
```

If you need to trace any session (not only your own):

```
 select sid,serial# from v$session
```

to look at sid of session and

```
begin
  sys.dbms_system.set_ev(sid, serial#, 10046, 12, '');
end;
```

Otherwise you can use logon trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SYS.TRACE_A_USER
AFTER
LOGON ON <some_db_user>.SCHEMA
DECLARE
user_sid NUMBER;
user_serial# NUMBER;
user_program VARCHAR2(48);
BEGIN
-- Collect the current user session details.
SELECT sid, serial#, UPPER(program)
INTO user_sid, user_serial#, user_program
FROM v$session
WHERE audsid = USERENV('SESSIONID');
-- Start tracing if the user is running the identified application.
IF user_program = 'SOMECODE.EXE' THEN
-- Enable tracing. Note level 12 tracing includes bind variable
-- and wait statistics.
sys.dbms_system.set_ev(user_sid, user_serial#, 10046, 12, '');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: FYI, sql_trace is now deprecated: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams205.htm#REFRN10208

Comment: That's why I have the word "now". Are you saying it's bad form to comment on old posts?